# C# - PIVOT on a Bit datatype in SQL Server & assign result to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wrote this query in SQL Server which gives output shown in image below.

Instead of zero I want check box column.

```
set @str =  STUFF ((Select ',' + QUOTENAME(CategoryName)
    From dbo.Master_ItemCategoryMaster
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

Print @str

set @query = N'Select [PlaceId],[PlaceName],' +@str +N'
               From
                   (Select ID as [PlaceId], CommonName as [PlaceName],(cast (ISNULL(PC.StatusId, 0) as tinyint)) as [StatusId],IC.CategoryName
                    From dbo.Master_CommonMaster CM 

        CROSS JOIN dbo.Master_ItemCategoryMaster IC 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Master_PlaceWiseCategory PC ON PC.PlaceId = CM.ID 
            AND PC.CategoryId = IC.CatID
        Where CM.TypeId = 2 and IC.ItemGroup ! = 101

    )AS M
    PIVOT
    (   
        MAX([StatusId]) For CategoryName IN ('+@str+N')
    )as P           
    '
     exec sp_executesql @query;
```

In query `StatusId` is a `bit` datatype column.

[image]

My question is, how do you `PIVOT` on a `bit` datatype in SQL Server & assign result to datagridview (Bit column works as checkbox)?

Comment: But you have converted `StatusId` to `tinyint` in pivot source query which should have fixed your problem

Comment: output shown is given by query i written

Comment: @Ranjeet Edit your Question add  C# code related to datagridview

Comment: @ Khurram Ali.in C# i use datagridviw1.datasource=dt. dt is output given by dataadapter after execute Query

Comment: @Ranjeet  the above query works fine ?? you just want to add checkbox in datagridview ?

Comment: @Khuram Ali.Can i add check box in datagridview using query.beacause dataGridview display check box if datatype is Boolean. in above code how we can define value of pivot column is bit/boolean.

Comment: @Ranjeet it would be better if you manually create columns and DataGridViewCheckbox column in your datagridview

Comment: want save & search data in this datagridview,so its not helping.can u give me solution using SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    declare @str as varchar(MAX)
declare @str1 as varchar(MAX)

    declare @query as nvarchar(MAX)

    set @str =  STUFF ((Select ',' + QUOTENAME(CategoryName)
    From dbo.Master_ItemCategoryMaster
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')




set @str1 =  STUFF ((Select ',' + 'cast('+ QUOTENAME(CategoryName)
+' as bit) as ' + QUOTENAME(CategoryName)
        From dbo.Master_ItemCategoryMaster
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')


    Print @str

    set @query = N' 
    Select [PlaceId],[PlaceName],' +@str1 +N'
    From
    (   
        Select ID as [PlaceId], CommonName as [PlaceName],(cast (ISNULL(PC.StatusId, 0) as tinyint)) as [Select],IC.CategoryName
        From dbo.Master_CommonMaster CM 

        CROSS JOIN dbo.Master_ItemCategoryMaster IC 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Master_PlaceWiseCategory PC ON PC.PlaceId = CM.ID 
            AND PC.CategoryId = IC.CatID
        Where CM.TypeId = 2 and IC.ItemGroup ! = 101

    )AS M
    PIVOT
    (   
        MAX([Select]) For CategoryName IN ('+@str+N')
    )as P           
    '
     exec sp_executesql @query;
```

String @str1(Dynamic Column List) is used as column list where column is cast as Bit
& @str is used in Pivot